# Should I approve these small edits in the review queue?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I was in the `suggested-edits` queue and noticed a single user making a large amount of small edits. Things like spelling and grammar (one or two word edits) but also bits of code and keyboard key icons (mostly this).

So while these edits may be correct, most of the are simply just changing ALT + F1 to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Should I approve such minor edits ? I only get 20 votes right ?

I think I should save my votes for better, more valuable edits but what do you guys do ? You can see what I mean for yourself in the queue.

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263640/allow-us-to-filter-out-tag-only-or-minimal-edits-from-suggested-edits-review

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm not a mod, so just sharing what I do:

- If those edits are the only edits the post needs: <kbd>Approve</kbd>
- If those are just some minor formatting and the post needs major rework: <kbd>Reject</kbd>

In-between these two extremes are: <kbd>Reject and edit</kbd> and <kbd>Improve edit</kbd>.  After the <kbd>Improve edit</kbd>, I leave a comment to the original editor on what to improve:

> Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my **edits** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **:-)**

Source for you to freely copy and re-use:

```
Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my **[edits]()** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **:-)**
```

where I put a link to the reviewed edits in-between the `()`...

If you <kbd>Reject</kbd>, or <kbd>Reject and edit</kbd>, no use leaving a comment to the original editor as he'll not be pinged and will only see your comment if he watches his edits like a hawk! (Thanks [@Muru](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) for pointing this out)

### And most important of all:

There are a bunch of reviewers out there!

<sub>Also small edits need reviewing!  Don't worry about your 20 points!</sub>

Comment: Just a small note; Mods don't set, for the lack of a better word, "rules". The whole community does. It's not a tyranny! :p

Comment: @Dan: you've never had a mod hammer come down on you have you?  **:P**

Comment: haha no :p but they usually only do to settle a dispute, or warn someone of bad behaviour. You've been bad I presume! :p

Comment: Unintentionally: yes.  Intentionally??? Probably, but I can't remember...

Answer (score 1):

Fabby's answer is excellent, as it explains how to deal with each single case.

I'll try to add something by addressing the thing from another point of view;

IMO a suggested edit, unlike an edit done by a 2K+ user, is meant to be almost perfect (completeness-wise), because otherwise (in order of importance):

- It wastes 2 reviewers' time
- It steals 2 points of reputation (minor, but to be fair that's what it does)

So while one might argue that a suggested edit per how minor it could be it's always an improvement, it's important to keep an iron hand and reject edits which not address almost all the problems in one post to avoid the queue be flooded with useless edits which the reviewers are reviewing for almost no reward.

Differently, an edit done by a 2K+ user can even just correct the most important things (even only the formatting), because that still improves the post but wastes no time other than the editor's time.