# Edit that removes only "Thanks " from post - should it be approved or rejected?

Tags: discussion

Today "suggested edits" queue suddenly increased to more than 20.

I observed the following in the edits:

- All the edits removing only "Thanks" (there are no other improvements).
- All are proposed by the same user.

Some examples of edit links you can find [here](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/480768) , [here](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/480745) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/480761) .

*I think that all the edits are done only to get reputation points.*

My Question:

What would be a good choice ? Approve or Reject ?

I found similar discussions on meta (thanks to @hg8).

[Why are edits removing "Thanks in advance" sometimes rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153074/why-are-edits-removing-thanks-in-advance-sometimes-rejected/153076#153076)

[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

It is not suitable to say  *minor* since there is no mistake  corrected or formatting improved.

Comment: @kos this might not be a dupe since it is specifically about edits that only remove "thanks", not minor edits in general. We got a whole load of those today.

Comment: @terdon I agree that maybe in this specific case simple "Thanks" removal should be rejected and edited, so yes, you've got a point there. Retracted

Comment: No, actually you're asking about a very specific case, although the first link in your answer seems to answer that: "Such edits are too minor and clog up the queue."

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14485/should-i-approve-these-small-edits-in-the-review-queue#comment25410_14485

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Personally, I rejected all of them with the following comment:

> Please don't clutter up the review queues with such minor edits. Wait until you have enough reputation to make them directly.

Minor edits that actually correct a mistake, or fix formatting or improve grammar or even typos are fine. Minor edits that simply remove thanks and leave the rest of the post untouched are just not worth it. Especially since, in many of those cases, there were other, more serious issues with the question that were not fixed.

So, yes, in my opinion, those edits should be rejected since they're not worth filling the review queues with. We can leave them to those users with enough rep to edit directly.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan rejects edits with typos. I try to take his attention to this post to show him, that typos fixing is normal. Typos were fixed for the next post: https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1014858

Comment: @gryu yes, that looks like a fine edit. I don't know why it would have been rejected. I suggest you post a new question on [META] and ask. Both reviewers are reasonable people, I'm sure they can explain.